# Stored procedure in Android with MySQL-connector-Java-3.0.17-ga- bin doesn't work

Tags: android, mysql

I have an issue when I try to call a stored procedure in Android, below is my code.

```
private List<LocationDO> search() {
    Connection connection = null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection();

        if (connection != null) {
          callableStatement =  connection.prepareCall("{call cy_sp_getLocation(?,?,?)}");
            callableStatement.setFloat(1, 48.782818f);
            callableStatement.setFloat(2, 24.62229f);
            callableStatement.setFloat(3, 0.5f);
            callableStatement.execute();
        }
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When execute this line

```
callableStatement = connection.prepareCall ("{call cy_sp_getLocation (?,?,?)"); throw "Callablestatments not supported.".
```

I used the connector for Android MySQL-connector-Java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar.

Comment: `Starting with Connector/J 3.1.1, stored procedures are supported when connecting to MySQL version 5.0 or newer using the CallableStatement interface. Currently, the getParameterMetaData() method of CallableStatement is not supported.`. See [5.2 JDBC API Implementation Notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html).

Comment: So, I use the MySql Workbench 6.3, and this code is developed in Android Studio. Do you want to show also  my Stored Procedure? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very very much, I solved this problem. First things what you have to do is to change the connector from data base, now i use mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar. Second things is to change the url to connect to data base: "jdbc:mysql://yourIP:3306/db?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" at the last, i will put my code below.

Comment: callableStatement =  connection.prepareCall("{call cy_sp_getLocation(?,?,?)}");
                callableStatement.setFloat(1, 47.782818f);
                callableStatement.setFloat(2, 24.62229f);
                callableStatement.setFloat(3, 0.5f);
                callableStatement.executeQuery();
                resultSet = callableStatement.getResultSet();
                while(resultSet.next()){
                   }